# Jquery UI Datepicker - How to highlight multiple date bgcolor with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know, lot of questions also in Stackoverflow. But did'nt get a working answer. Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

**I want to highlight multiple date of current month.** Eg: 02 March 2017, 10 March 2017, 25 March 2017.

My code:

```js
 $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I got the answer.
Here is the working solution.

```js
var dates = ['03/02/2017', '03/10/2017', '03/25/2017'];

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    //defaultDate: new Date('03/10/2017'), // this line is for testing
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays
});

function highlightDays(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        if (new Date(dates[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
            return [true, 'highlight'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

```css
td.highlight > a {
 background: #E50104!important;
 color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can handle it using `beforeShowDay` event, Here is the [reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Following the code example:

```js
 $(function() {
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        var a = new Date(2017, 2, 10); // April 10, 2012
        var b = new Date(2017, 2, 20); // April 20, 2012
        return [true, a <= d && d <= b ? "my-class" : ""];
    }

});
});
```

```css
.my-class {
background: red;
}
.my-class a {
background: lime !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: Could you update the answer with only highlight the date 10th & 25th March?

Comment: I will update, however you can play around with the selection of multiple date as the reference link I have added in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use library [MultiDatesPicker v1.6.3 for jQuery UI](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

[image]